# Silently Rewrite URL to sub-sub-directory in NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am wondering if someone can please help me with something that I am racking my brain with. I have a folder structure like this;

```
/var/www/<user>/<user>/
```

So to see the files currently with NGINX I need to naviagte to;

```
https://<host>/<user>/<user>
```

What I want to do is make it so I can navigate to the following and it is re-written silently in the backend.

```
https://<host>/<user>/
```

To achieve this, I have written the following rule

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/(.*)$ {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /$1/$uri/index.html /$1/$uri;
}
```

It seemed to work once but since it unfortunately keeps rewriting in a continuous loop. I've tried a few things and understand why it loops but I cannot work out how to stop it.

Now, you may be wondering why have this folder structure. It's a long story but basically I want a user to only have access to their files and with Chroot (for sftp) the root dir must be owned by root so it needs a subdirectory to make it work due to permissions.

Comment: Does `/var/www/` **only** contain `/user/user/` directories? Can you edit the question and add the complete `server` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anyone has this issue in future, the problem what that the first match ($1) was matching incorrectly, it contained everything in between the slashes. So it would match like this;

```
/<user>/
$1 = <user>

/<user>/<subdir>
$1 = /<user>/<subdir>/

/<user>/<subdir>/<file>
$1 = /<user>/<subdir>/
```

To fix this so that $1 was always only the first slash part I changed the NGINX config to this:

```
location ~ /([^/]*)/(.*)?$ {
    try_files $uri /$1/$1/$2 /$1/$1/$2/index.html /$1/$1/index.html;
}
```

This will match like the following:

```
/<user>/
$1 = <user>

/<user>/<subdir>
$1 = <user>

/<user>/<subdir>/<file>
$1 = <user>
```

Now it all matches correctly and works fine! I hope that this someday helps someone else with the same issue.

Comment: Apparently I can't because you need 250 rep to close :) took me a while to figure that one out.

Comment: Please, could you try use this post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved ? You can close your own question, when you find a solution by yourself. Thanks,